# .htaccess: force www except subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, subdirectory

Until now I have used this code to redirect request from **example.com/url/to/page** to **www.example.com/url/to/page**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Recently I added shortlinks like **example.com/x/abc** to my page
These links should not have "www" at the beginning

I tried

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    !^www\.  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^x/     [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but this does not work. Firebug shows 2 redirects: non-www to www and then shortlink to longlink instead of just 1 redirect shortlink to longlink.  I also empty cache each time I change .htaccess

How can I achieve the correct redirection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    !^www\.  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/x/     [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

`%{REQUEST_URI}` starts matching from a slash at the start.