# .htaccess: force www including subfolder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have this code in the .htaccess-file of my root:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This changes `mysite.com` into `www.mysite.com` .

I've put the same .htaccess-file inside a folder named "v2". I want `mysite.com/v2/start.php` to change to `www.mysite.com/v2/start.php` . This doesn't happen, although [other resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18814335/htaccess-force-www-except-subfolder) claim it should work.

Anyone has any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have u tried rewrite base RewriteBase v2

Comment: An htaccess rule set in a higher directory should be applied to all sub directories. The problem/fix might be in the first htaccess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! Any idea how I can force https too?

Comment: split it. first force https then move to www
e.g. RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on

Comment: Works like a charm!